# Can I write IO statements inside a dll?

Tags: dll

This is a newbie question. Can I write statements like `printf` or open a file inside a dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a file is certainly possible in all cases.

However, using `printf()` depends on whether the executable calling your DLL is a console program or not. If it's a GUI program, then there is nowhere for the `printf()` output to go, so it will not appear. If it's a console program, you'll see the output on the console.

Comment: @Bruce: If you don't specify a full path, then your file will be opened relative to the current directory (which may be something other than what you expect). When you try to open a file, what's the error code you're getting? And if you don't know *that*, then find out how to debug your code using a debugger. All debuggers support debugging DLL code, even if you don't have the code for the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and its title are asking two different questions.  But the answer to the question *body* is yes -- libraries can certainly use those functions.

`printf` might not do anything though, depending on whether standard output has been closed by the program using the library.